# Is it a good idea to storage validations in DAO?

Tags: design-patterns, dao

I have web application. The structure: controller which take an entity and DAO which save the entity and making some other actions. Is this a good idea to check stateless validations (size of name for example) in controller and sate validations (duplicate email in db for example) in DAO. Is there good practices for that? Can you advise some resources or book to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to storage validations in DAO?

No, it isn't. DAO - as the name suggested - should be used only for the purpose of storing/retrieving objects from some source of data. Most of validations are a kind of business logics and thus should not belong to DAO.

However, due to performance issue, sometimes it is acceptable to put *some* business logics into DAO. This often happens when the criteria of object retrieving reflects business logics. For example, to get the night-shift employee with highest salary, it's quite inefficient to load all employees into memory then apply the business logic to find such an employee. Instead, we can let the DAO execute a simple SQL query to do that.

Regarding your example of email validation, yes, you can put that logic into your DAO. But as a good practice, always name your DAO methods so that they are responsible for storing/retrieving objects, like: `findEmployeeByEmail(String email)`.

In short, putting business/validation logics into DAO is sometimes acceptable, but try to make it minimal.

Comment: It’s business logic layer (also called domain layer) which is different from controllers/DAO. For small apps (where you don’t really need *separation of concerns*) you can put business logics into controllers. Notice that the job of pure controllers is not doing business logics, but interpreting user requests and forwarding to domain layer.